# How should I go about synchronizing sound effects with UI animations in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio, animation

I want to play some sound effects while animating an UI element (e.g. playing a movement sound while an UI object is moving), which requires precise timing and synchronization.

I really can't figure out which framework I should be using from the descriptions in the [Multimedia Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6). So I need your kind help in choosing one.

What I want to do is:

- Play short (max 10 seconds) sound effects (e.g. a button tap sound).
- Being able to synchronize some of them with UI animations (e.g. a view appearance/disappearance).

I tried using the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function from the AudioToolbox framework, sometimes it works great, but sometimes the sound won't play instantly. For example when a button is clicked, its action is performed before the sound is played, even though the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound is called first in the button's action method.

Thanks in advance,

Mota

Comment: It'd be nice if you could update with a solution that worked for you in practical terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing audio waveforms into an already running RemoteIO Audio Unit configured with short buffers will have the lowest possible audio latency.  The cost of this is a more complex to use API and the need for uncompressed audio assets.